# Class 'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User' not found

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I did something and now when I try to log on using the standard Laravel Auth implimentation I get the following error

> FatalErrorException in User.php line 9: Class
>   'Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User' not found

**edit** User.php does not exist in `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth` and `composer update` did not fix it

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After a `composer update`, if you still have this issue, run another command: `composer dump-autoload`

> This command won’t download a thing. It just regenerates the list of
>   all classes that need to be included in the project
>   (autoload_classmap.php). Ideal for when you have a new class inside
>   your project.

To summary, this will update the autoloader class map and include all components available for the project.

Does not forget to check if the correct library is included in your composer file :)

If it's still not working, try `composer update --no-scripts`
This fix many issues of libraries due to internal error during package installation. (usefull for production mode)

Comment: That didn't fix it. I also tried `composer install` see my edit for more details

Comment: I added another tips. This one worked for me. > `composer update --no-scripts`

Answer (score 1):

Check if `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/User.php` file exists. If it's not, run this command:

```
composer update
```

Comment: User does not exist in that directory even after running `composer update`.

Comment: Backup the project and clear `vendor` directory with `rm -rf vendor/*`. Then run `composer update` again.

Comment: even that didn't work but there are other files in that folder `AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers.php
AuthenticatesUsers.php
RedirectsUsers.php
RegistersUsers.php
ResetsPasswords.php
ThrottlesLogins.php`

Comment: If you'd clear `vendor` you'd not see any files. Try to remove the directory manually and then run the command. It should reinstall all packages.

Comment: What version of laravel are you using? The latest one?

Answer (score 0):

I have a same issue what I did is remove composer.lock and run composer install. It works fine for me.